# Windows IDE for AIX application

Tags: windows, aix, ide

I'm working on a C application based on AIX 5.3 using VI as an editor, 
I need a windows IDE (open source or commercial) that can:

- modify the source code more easily
- compile as if I'm under AIX
- manage multiuser access and synchronization

I found out about Rational Developer for AIX and Linux, have you any other suggestions ?

Comment: Consider asking at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: .... and then remove the question from here.

Comment: What does an IDE have to do with multiuser access? If you want a Windows application, why are you asking on a Unix site? Anyway, [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Windows application.

Comment: @Gilles We're accessing to our C programs based on AIX via telnet, if we use an IDE and two developers of the team modify the same file, that IDE has to manage multiuser access ..I'm asking on a unix site because the IDE I'm looking for has to work with a unix platform

Comment: @Alma IDEs don't manage multiuser access. That's very far from their job. Different developers might use different IDEs. Each developer has their own source tree, developers never work on the same files: that's what version control is for. If you aren't using version control, you need to set it up yesterday.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for making things clear for me ...I need to know is there any IDE that I could use directly in AIX or I have to use X window server to visualise it on windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about xming? It is a x window manager for windows, that way you can be running programs on your Aix machine and display them on your windows box. That way you can continue with your work as if you were in Aix, use vi or whatever IDE you might like code::blocks or whatever.

But if you are only going to use vi, gcc or the likes, with a simple ssh session you'll be ok. In that case putty is a great client.

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you give me a tutorial that can help me use xming with an IDE ? I'm using putty to acces to AIX ressources

Comment: Just download xming from http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ and install it. I thought you already had and IDE on your AIX, seems you don't. Check https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/c_c_cobol_ide_for_aix?lang=en for an IDE, install it on Aix and launch from Xming that IDE, you can do that with `xlaunch` from xming. The window that opens lets you specify the program you want to run on AIX, the machine where AIX is, user, password. When you have done al that the window of the IDE running on AIX will appear in a Windows window.

Comment: Thanks YoMismo for your help but I didn't find any IDE in that link could you please give me a direct link to an IDE ?